# how to send/Post json data from public network to private network in Codeignitor framework?

Tags: php, json, php-curl

how to send/Post  json data from public network to private network in Codeignitor framework ?
i
I want to post json data from Public network to private network using php (codeignitor Framework).
while form submitting, based on condition while closing request, i needed this requirement.
using php CURL method, from Public network as : https://medha.co.in/rewamp_service/index.php/rfq/rfq_compare_multi
to Private network as :
http://192.168.132.12/rewamp/index.php/rfq/getPublicData
and I need return response from private network.

Comment: You could open a port in your router's firewall and forward the connection but it's a big security risk. Why is this application on a private network?

Comment: A "private network" is by definition _private_, which means it cannot be accessed from a public network, unless you specifically create something for the public network to access a local resource in the private network.